# Eclipse hide .idea folder in Navigator and ignore at commit to VCS

Tags: eclipse, svn, intellij-idea

I have imported a Java project that has been set up using eclipse Luna (v 4.4.0) in IntelliJ Idea 14. Everything works fine, but when i switch back to eclipse, I see some newly created .idea folders in the navigator view. How to hide them from the navigator view? How to configure svn, that they will be ignored at my next commit?

Answer (score 0):

You can use command line to ignore specific files in svn

```
svn propset svn:ignore "*.iml" .
```